# Orientdb Studio Graph View - Words Cut Off

Tags: orientdb

I have casually been experimenting with OrientDB at work for a couple of years, but one thing that really bothers me is that the Studio Graph view seems to cut off the text inside the vertices.  Actually, the problem is not that they're cut off, but that the white text matches the white background, and since the text doesn't wrap, the text outside of the vertices becomes invisible.  It doesn't seem to matter what version I use, but currently I'm using v2.2.

Here's what I mean:
[OrientDB Studio Graph View - Words Cut Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUkLd.png)

I have many times toyed with the idea of using OrientDB kind of like a mind-map - a way to store information as it is learned, and then illustrate it using the Graph view for others to see and understand.  If it was just me it wouldn't be so bad, but I can't show it the way it is, because of this cut-off issue.

I've tried changing the radius of the vertices but then the edges get crowded and unusable.  I've tried changing other settings via "select * from _studio" - but the changes didn't seem to "stick".  I was hoping to find a way to increase both the radii and the length of the edges.  I didn't want to resort to using Neo4j since I've already invested time in learning OrientDB, but it seems they have this feature out-of-the-box.

Is there any way to make the graph view more manageable when character lengths are a little longer?  I appreciate any input!

Comment: Could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: The graph editor is just unusable, IMO. Densely connected graphs (even with only a dozen or so nodes) are absolutely unreadable, since the nodes are squeezed close together and the edges just turn into a rat's nest of lines and overlaid text. It's hard to take something seriously that hasn't gotten even minimal usability tweaking. This is fun, too: select a single node. Double click it. Watch your browser freeze as it tries to graph the entire frickin database for no reason.